# Company uses our own cookies versus its own cookies

Tags: possessive-pronouns

The Cookie Policy of a company is quoted below.
Should it not be: "uses **its** own and third-party cookies"?

A different issue but I guess it should also say "analyse users' experiences" and as they usually
use American English this might be even better: "**analyze users'** experiences".

*TechHero uses our own and third-party cookies to improve your navigation experience, analyse users experiences and offer you content of interest.
Please provide your authorization to use this website and to permanently remove this message by clicking on the "Accept Cookies" button. Read more about our Cookie Policy*

Comment: Please ask a single question, indicating your research. Proofreading questions are off-topic, and you seem to be trying to list every fault in an unassuming document, rather than asking a single, substantive question.

Comment: This is a mistake that I have seen in many a presidential speech. One wonders why speechwriters can't get the pronoun its, right.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree that there is an incongruity involved in

- *TechHero uses our own and third-party cookies to ...*

The company is given singular verb agreement (uses) twinned with a plural-form possessive ('our') *relating to the same referent*. Switching to 'its' certainly averts this clash, but 'third-party's' the company ... that company, not our company. The meaning is altered; there is a disowning.

While notional agreement works better here:

- *TechHero use our own and third-party cookies to ...*

this still sounds unnatural. I'd rewrite to

- *We at TechHero use our own and third-party cookies to ...*

or

- *At TechHero, we use our own and third-party cookies to ...*

Answer (score 1):

<s>TechHero uses our own and third-party cookies</s>

Either

**TechHero** uses **its** own and third-party cookies -> *its* has as its referent *TechHero* and both are the third person.

**We** use **our** own and third-party cookies -> *our* has as its referent *we* and both are the second person plural.